# How to download image using RxAlamofire

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rxalamofire

```
func showImageForUrl(url: String) -> Observable<Async<Any>> {
    let result = RxAlamofire
        .requestJSON(.get,
                     url,
                     parameters: nil)
        .flatMap { (response, json) -> Observable<Any> in
            return Observable.just(json)
        }.async()
    return result
}
```

url String  "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-KhiJ6WYQn8Q/T7ZXxb_KHxI/AAAAAAAABvM/_l134PCuEcA/s1600/dog+photos+3.jpg"

I'm trying this but the end result is an error.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one of the issue is the format of your request: it should be `requestData(...)` instead `requestJSON(...)` to download data then convert it into image.

Here is an example a bit simpler than the previous code

```swift
func showImageForUrl(url: String) -> Observable<UIImage?> {
    return RxAlamofire
        .requestData(.get, url)
        .map({ (response,data) -> UIImage? in
            return UIImage(data: data)
        })
}
```

You can use it as following

```swift
showImageForUrl(myUrl)
    .bind(to: myImageView.rx.image)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

You can go even further by filter out when invalid response, or when `UIImage` is nil, etc. Hope it helps.